# Why an error occurs on apache superset "An error occurred while fetching table metadata/removing the table schema. Plscontact your administrator"?

Tags: permissions, roles, apache-superset, gamma, flask-appbuilder

I assigned the Gamma and Sqllab roles to users and granted schema and database access permissions to the Gamma role for specific tables. SQL queries can be executed in Sql Lab without any issues. However, when attempting to select or remove tables in the "See Table Schema" feature, an error message appeared in a popup window stating "An error occurred while fetching table metadata. Please contact your administrator." As an administrator, I am able select/remove table without any issues. What additional permissions should be added to resolve this issue?

I tried to give several other permissions and tried to debug this error on the code side.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue added to Gamma role these permissions:

1. can expanded on TableSchemaView
2. can delete on TableSchemaView
3. can post on TableSchemaView